# Margin not being applied in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have applied a margin to the top of the blue section below, however it doesn't seem to be showing. Also it seems to be right up against the left side of the screen, any ideas how to fix?

The problem shows when CSS Sheet 2 is being applied

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css" 
     media="screen and (max-width:900px)">
</header>

<body>

<div class="m1">
    <p>My content</p>
</div>

<div class="m2">
    <p>My content</p>
</div>

<div class="m3">
    <p>My content</p>
</div>


</body>
```

CSS Sheet 1

```
body {
    width:1000px;
    margin:20px auto;
    max-width:100vw;
}

.m1 {
    background-color:red;
    width:30%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
}

.m2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:30%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2.5%;
}

.m3 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:30%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2.5%;
}
```

CSS Sheet 2

```
body {

}

.m1 {
    width:42.5%;
}

.m2 {
    width:42.5%;
}

.m3 {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    width:85%;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: none;` from `.m3` class of CSS Sheet 2.

Answer (score 2):

**Flex approach.**

> Adjust `margin` according to your requirement.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.m1 {
  width: calc(50vw - 60px);
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.m2 {
  width: calc(50vw - 60px);
  background: green;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.m3 {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="m1">
    <p>My content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m2">
    <p>My content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m3">
    <p>My content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have not cleared the `float` which you applied for `.m1` and `.m2` selectors. Try adding a div to clear below m1 and m2. Try this code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css" media="screen and (max-width:900px)">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="m1">
      <p>My content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="m2">
      <p>My content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>

    <div class="m3">
      <p>My content</p>
    </div>
</body>

body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.m1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
}

.m2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.m3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

body {}

.m1 {
  width: 42.5%;
}

.m2 {
  width: 42.5%;
}

.m3 {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I'm just a bit confused though as I used "clear:both" for m3 in CSS Sheet 2?

Comment: If my answer worked, how about ticking my answer as the right answer. And about clear, if you have already used `clear:both` css in your stylesheet, you don't need to define it again, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using shorthand property on m1 but not using on m3

```
.m3 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:30%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 2.5% 0 2.5%;
}
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/758rrLua/